# Multiple logical index select numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Well, if we want to choose certain values to remain the same, and set others values to zero in a numpy array, we can

```py
A = A == 1
```

if A has only 4 unique numbers 0,1,2,3.

However, if I want to select N different values, like

```py
A = np.where(A==1 or A==2, A)
```

but this does not work, and the conditions are not neccessarily for 2 values only. How can i implement this idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a note when using multiple conditions, use the `bitwise OR` operator (`|`) and enclose each condition in parenthesis:

```
A = np.where((A == 1) | (A == 2), A, 0)
```

And for this task, you can use [`numpy.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html):

```
A = np.where(numpy.isin(A, [1, 2]), A, 0)
```